# What goes to the __init_array?

Tags: c, gcc, ld, libc, newlib

I have a Cortex-M3 project compiled with GCC. The startup_LPC177x_8x.s code copies the initialized data from flash to RAM, initializes the **bss**, calls the clock initialization  `SystemInit`. Before calling the `_main` function the code also calls the function `_libc_init_array`.

The [__libc_init_array](http://newlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.18.0/init_8c-source.html) function calls all initialization routines that are defined in the `__preinit_array`, calls the `_init` function, and all routines that are defined in the `__init_array`:

```
void __libc_init_array (void)
{
    size_t count;
    size_t i;

    count = __preinit_array_end - __preinit_array_start;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        __preinit_array_start[i] ();

    _init ();

    count = __init_array_end - __init_array_start;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        __init_array_start[i] ();
}
```

With GDB I could find that the `__preinit_array` is empty (start==end), and that the second call to `__init_array_start[i] ()` crashes.

I have no idea what functions are included in this array. The linker script causes all `.init.array.*` section to be located here. But how do I find the corresponding `.o` and source files?

```
.init_array :
{
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
} >FLASH
```

Comment: don't quote me on this, but afaik, gcc places functions called with __attribute__((constructor)) into __init_array.

Comment: It's a plain C project. There are no C++ constructors. And I am convinced that I never used this attribute. How do I identify the origin and meaning of such constructs.

Comment: read the gcc manual ;) the  `__attribute__((*))` construct is used by gcc to enable attributes for functions and variables and such. one of these attributes is `constructor` which has nothing to do with c++ constructers. On program start, and on shared library load, all functions declared with that attribute are executed in an undefined order. see also http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: by the way, did you have any success using objdump as I suggested in my answer below?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin RTFM is always true. But I am looking for the source or library file that has been dropped tot the array. The manual describes what you could read when you found the location. But I am still in the phase of looking for the location and reason for object files the include a `.init_array*` section.

Comment: https://maskray.me/blog/2021-11-07-init-ctors-init-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I can help you here -

run

```
objdump -D -j .init_array <your-application>
```

and you will recieve a list of adresses, like

```
Disassembly of section .init_array:

c1008db4 <.init_array>:
c1008db4:   c1000000    .word   0xc1000000
c1008db8:   c1000a68    .word   0xc1000a68
c1008dbc:   c1000b64    .word   0xc1000b64
c1008dc0:   c1000c04    .word   0xc1000c04
c1008dc4:   c1000c68    .word   0xc1000c68
```

now, if you have compiled this thing yourself, you can now run

```
addr2line 0xc1000a68 -e <your-application>
```

to get filename and line number of the functions in question.

Does that help?

Comment: The objdump 2.22.0.20121207 does not show `.word` but tries to disassemble the bytes. But I can use the raw bytes in the second column as the address. There is no addr2line in my GCC installation. But I can use the map file manually and found a corresponding function `register_fini`. This function reads a value checks for condition and returns. Unfortunately the code in `__libc_init_array` goes somhow to the nirvana after the return.

Comment: @harper weird - sounds like it reads out of bounds of the init array and tries to jump into random adresses (UB). can you find out the value of `__init_array_end - __init_array_start`? maybe your toolchain is glitched.